# No suitable driver found error in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, intellij-idea

i'm a beginner in database,as i switched to Intellij idea now i'm trying to fetch database information but still it's giving me this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Raj\IdeaProjects\untitled11\out\production\untitled11;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain JdbcSelectTest
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:9999/ebookshop
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at JdbcSelectTest.main(JdbcSelectTest.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and here is my `JdbcSelectTest.java` code:

```
import java.sql.*;              // Use classes in java.sql package

// JDK 6 and above
public class JdbcSelectTest {   // Save as JdbcSelectTest.java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement  stmt = null;
        try {
            // Step 1: Allocate a database "Connection" object
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:9999/ebookshop", "root", "1234"); // MySQL

            // Step 2: Allocate a "Statement" object in the Connection
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            // Step 3: Execute a SQL SELECT query, the query result
            //  is returned in a "ResultSet" object.
            String strSelect = "select title, price, qty from books";
            System.out.println("The SQL query is: " + strSelect); // Echo For debugging
            System.out.println();

            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);

            // Step 4: Process the ResultSet by scrolling the cursor forward via next().
            //  For each row, retrieve the contents of the cells with getXxx(columnName).
            System.out.println("The records selected are:");
            int rowCount = 0;
            while(rset.next()) {   // Move the cursor to the next row
                String title = rset.getString("title");
                double price = rset.getDouble("price");
                int    qty   = rset.getInt("qty");
                System.out.println(title + ", " + price + ", " + qty);
                ++rowCount;
            }
            System.out.println("Total number of records = " + rowCount);

        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Step 5: Always free resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null) stmt.close();  // This closes ResultSet too
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
            } catch(SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my `raj.sql` query...

```
create database if not exists ebookshop;

use ebookshop;

drop table if exists books;
create table books (
  id int,
  title varchar(50),
  author varchar(50),
  price float,
  qty int,
  primary key (id));

insert into books values (1001, 'Java for dummies', 'Tan Ah Teck', 11.11, 11);
insert into books values (1002, 'More Java for dummies', 'Tan Ah Teck', 22.22, 22);
insert into books values (1003, 'More Java for more dummies', 'Mohammad Ali', 33.33, 33);
insert into books values (1004, 'A Cup of Java', 'Kumar', 44.44, 44);
insert into books values (1005, 'A Teaspoon of Java', 'Kevin Jones', 55.55, 55);

select * from books;
```

I have succesfully downloded Mysql connector please see my [pic](http://postimg.org/image/gjwcu04i5/)

**Edited:**

After using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` Now it's showing new error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at JdbcSelectTest.main(JdbcSelectTest.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forgot about

```
//step 0 : register driver to driver manager
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: `Class.forName` can throw `ClassNotFoundException` so you need to handle it. Wrap this line with `try-catch` blocks, or declare your method to throw `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Is your jar with mysql driver in `File > Project Structure > Libraries`?

Answer (score 0):

Download Mysql jdbc driver jar file and add it to your classpath

Comment: @user3585755 In that case, check your classpath. The program isn't able to locate the driver jar file.

Comment: Now to set that class path actually intellij idea download it itself so how to navigate it's driver location?

Comment: @user3585755, Intellij downloads this jar automatically so that the database plugin can work, it does not add it to your project's classpath